I want to understand the fundamental difference/connection between DFS, DFT and DTFT
I'm an EE student and I seem to miss some basic concept of my Signals course.
We have learned about all the different Fourier methods available, but I don't seem to find a difference/understand it.
As an example for myself I've tried plotting in python a basic discrete square wave a(n):
$$
\ a(n) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{for } |n| < 100  \\
  0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases} \
$$
I have tried to calculate the Discrete fourier series coefficients of this signal a_k and when I plotted it in python I've got something that looks like a dirichlet kernal:

But whenever I try and calculate and plot the DFT of this signal, I get something that looks more like a sinc function:

which is strange to me because the formula is basically almost the same (except a factor).
Now I understand that a DFT is a sampling of a single period of the DTFT, hence I cannot plot the DTFT of the signal in continuous form, hence we have the DFT to have discrete samples of it in spectrum. But shouldn't the DFS and the DFT coefficients represent the same thing?
Thank you.

You might this helpful: https://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/LODZLECT/Lodz5.pdf. The difference are in whether signals are period/aperiodic and discrete/continuous.  in either domain. The properties are hard linked: what's periodic in one domain is discrete in the other (in all 4 permutations).

Be careful, Hil, some might differentiate between finite-length and periodic.  But I wouldn't do that.

The Dirichlet Kernel and the Sinc Function are actually quite close as the number of samples get large (you can interpret, quite accurately, the Dirichlet Kernel as an aliased Sinc function).  The second plot the OP presents does not look like a Sinc function at all given the negative peaks that are nearly as large as the positive peaks. Without seeing the actual code that generated this, I suspect that the OP is plotting the real part of a zero padded sequence (which will provide samples of the DTFT, since the DTFT is the DFT when the sequences are allowed to extend (zero padded in the OP's case) to $\pm \infty$. Further the OP has computed the sequence starting at $t=0$ (or $n=0$ if we want to use discrete samples as the time index) and extending out in the positive time direction only. This results in a phase shift on the resulting frequency domain result (an offset in time is a linear phase in frequency), causing the complex result in frequency to rotate in phase between the real and imaginary axis.  This can be confirmed by plotting the imaginary components as well which should appear quite similar to the second plot (when the real part goes to zero the imaginary component will go to a maximum). Further if the OP plots the magnitude only, both results should be quite similar since the effective offset in time between the two approaches is only affecting the phase.
